# I have Cold water upstairs but NO hot water. However I have hot and cold in my kitchen.

Tags: hot-water

The cold water pressure is great upstairs but I do not have any hot water going up stairs I  turn the hot water on it makes a big loud bang but nothing comes out

Comment: A bit more information might be helpful. Does the faucet has separate hot / cold knobs or 1 mixing knob? If their separate, if you only turn on the hot, does water come out, but it's cold or no water at all? How far is the 2nd floor faucet from the kitchen? How old is the house / pipes? Recently built or a century old house? Do you see water leaks anywhere? Do you see any access panels or holes on the other side of the wall of the 2nd floor faucet? Have you checked the hot water shut off valve inside the cabinet / under the faucet?

Comment: If it happened recently then check your faucet cartridge,

Answer (score 0):

Is there only one fixture (sink, whatever) upstairs?  If there is more than one, do any of them get hot water?  When you say nothing comes out... no water at all, or water that isn't hot?  If no water at all, the first thing that comes to mind is a worn out/loose faucet where the internal components are slamming like a piston when the faucet is opened and creating an obstruction.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.